# OpenLayers 4 styling draw features

Tags: openlayers

How can I change the color (randomly or iterate through a specific array) of a feature that I draw on the map?

This is my code:

```
// marker layer
Msource = new ol.source.Vector();

markLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: Msource,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
      opacity: 0.95,
      src: 'http://www..../images/mapplot.png',
     color: "red"
    })
  })
});
```

I have a button that when I click on it allows me to draw that marker with this code:

```
var mark;
var counter = "true";

function addMark(Type) {

  counter = "true";

  mark = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: Msource,
    type: Type
  });

  // limit the marker to 4
  if (Msource.getFeatures().length < 4) {

    map.addInteraction(mark);

    // occurs when you finish to draw the current element
    mark.on("drawend", function(){
      counter = "true";
      drawingMarker();
    });

    // occurs just after you finish to draw the current element
    markLayer.on("change", function(){
      map.removeInteraction(mark);

      if (counter == "true") {
        counter = "false";
        var ind = Msource.getFeatures().length - 1;
        Msource.getFeatures()[ind].setId(MarkId - 1);
      }

    });

  } else {

    map.removeInteraction(mark);

    // show max marker message
    $(".maxmarkers").css("display", "inline");

  }

} // end addDraw


$("#Marker").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  addMark("Point");
});
```

I use some other function like remove function and drag feature, for this reason, I assign an incremented `ID`.

How can I change the color of the marker randomly or through an array (the max marker are 4)?

Here a screenshot of how it looks at the moment, the marker is not `red` because I'm using another image at the moment but I have another (always png) that change color based on the color in the layer.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Credits to [Pavlos](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/60673/pavlos) who answer my question in https://gis.stackexchange.com

```
var myColors = ['red','blue','green','yellow'];
var iterator = -1;

function styleFn(f){

var retSytle;


  if (typeof(f.get('styledwithcolor')) != 'undefined'){
  console.log("1",typeof(f.get('styledwithcolor')))

  retSytle = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 6,
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'white',
            width: 2
          }),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: f.get('styledwithcolor')
          })
        })
      });
  } else {
  console.log("2",typeof(f.get('styledwithcolor')))
  if (iterator == myColors.length-1){
  iterator =-1
  }
iterator = iterator + 1;
  f.set('styledwithcolor',myColors[iterator]);
  retSytle = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 6,
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'white',
            width: 2
          }),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: myColors[iterator]
          })
        })
      });
  console.log("retSytle",retSytle)
  }
  return [retSytle];
}

markLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: Msource,
  style: styleFn
});
```